# How to print JSON objects in AWK

Tags: json, awk, text-mining

I was looking for some built-in functions inside awk to easily generate JSON objects. I came across several answers and decided to create my own.

I'd like to generate JSON from multidimensional arrays, where I store table style data, and to use separate and dynamic definition of JSON schema to be generated from that data.

Desired output:

```
{
"Name": JanA
"Surname": NowakA
"ID": 1234A
"Role": PrezesA
}
{
"Name": JanD
"Surname": NowakD
"ID": 12341D
"Role": PrezesD
}
{
"Name": JanC
"Surname": NowakC
"ID": 12342C
"Role": PrezesC
}
```

Input file:

```
pierwsza linia
druga linia
trzecia linia

dane wspólników
imie JanA
nazwisko NowakA
pesel 11111111111A
funkcja PrezesA

imie Ja"nD
nazwisko NowakD
pesel 11111111111
funkcja PrezesD

imie JanC
nazwisko NowakC
pesel 12342C
funkcja PrezesC

czwarta linia

reprezentanci

imie Tomek
```

Based on input file i created a multidimensional array:

```
JanA  NowaA 1234A PrezesA
JanD  NowakD 12341D PrezesD
JanC  NowakC 12342C PrezesC
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON.  Try pasting it into [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My updated awk implementation of simple array printer with regex based validation for each column(running using gawk):

```
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t]+$/, "", s); return s }
function sTrim(s){
    return rtrim(ltrim(s));
}

function jsonEscape(jsValue) {
    gsub(/\\/, "\\\\", jsValue)
    gsub(/"/,  "\\\"", jsValue)
    gsub(/\b/, "\\b",  jsValue)
    gsub(/\f/, "\\f",  jsValue)
    gsub(/\n/, "\\n",  jsValue)
    gsub(/\r/, "\\r",  jsValue)
    gsub(/\t/, "\\t",  jsValue)

    return jsValue
}

function jsonStringEscapeAndWrap(jsValue) {
    return "\42" jsonEscape(jsValue) "\42"
}

function jsonPrint(contentArray, contentRowsCount, schemaArray){    
    result = ""
    schemaLength = length(schemaArray)
    for (x = 1; x <= contentRowsCount; x++) {
        result = result "{"
        for(y = 1; y <= schemaLength; y++){

            result = result "\42" sTrim(schemaArray[y]) "\42:" sTrim(contentArray[x, y])

             if(y < schemaLength){
                result = result ","
            }

        }        
        result = result "}"
        if(x < contentRowsCount){
            result = result ",\n"
        }
    }
    return result
}

function jsonValidateAndPrint(contentArray, contentRowsCount, schemaArray, schemaColumnsCount, errorArray){  
    result = ""
    errorsCount = 1
    for (x = 1; x <= contentRowsCount; x++) {
        jsonRow = "{"
        for(y = 1; y <= schemaColumnsCount; y++){

            regexValue = schemaArray[y, 2]
            jsonValue = sTrim(contentArray[x, y])
            isValid = jsonValue ~ regexValue            

            if(isValid == 0){
                errorArray[errorsCount, 1] = "\42" sTrim(schemaArray[y, 1]) "\42"
                errorArray[errorsCount, 2] = "\42Value " jsonValue " not match format: " regexValue " \42"
                errorArray[errorsCount, 3] = x
                errorsCount++
                jsonValue = "null"
            }            

            jsonRow = jsonRow "\42" sTrim(schemaArray[y, 1]) "\42:" jsonValue

            if(y < schemaColumnsCount){
                jsonRow =  jsonRow ","
            }
        }        
        jsonRow = jsonRow "}"
        result = result jsonRow

        if(x < contentRowsCount){
            result = result ",\n"
        }
    }

    return result
}

BEGIN{  
    rowsCount =1
    matchCount = 0
    errorsCount = 0
    shareholdersJsonSchema[1, 1] = "Imie"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[2, 1] = "Nazwisko"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[3, 1] = "PESEL"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[4, 1] = "Funkcja"

    shareholdersJsonSchema[1, 2] = "\\.*"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[2, 2] = "\\.*"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[3, 2] = "^[0-9]{11}$"
    shareholdersJsonSchema[4, 2] = "\\.*"


    errorsSchema[1] = "PropertyName"    
    errorsSchema[2] = "Message"
    errorsSchema[3] = "PositionIndex"

    resultSchema[1]= "ShareHolders"
    resultSchema[2]= "Errors"
}

/dane wspólników/,/czwarta linia/{      

    if(/imie/ || /nazwisko/ || /pesel/ || /funkcja/){

        if(/imie/){
            shareholdersArray[rowsCount, 1] = jsonStringEscapeAndWrap($2)
            matchCount++ 
        }
        if(/nazwisko/){ 
            shareholdersArray[rowsCount, 2] = jsonStringEscapeAndWrap($2)
            matchCount ++ 
        }
        if(/pesel/){             
            shareholdersArray[rowsCount, 3] = $2
            matchCount ++ 
        }
        if(/funkcja/){ 
            shareholdersArray[rowsCount, 4] = jsonStringEscapeAndWrap($2)
            matchCount ++
        }

        if(matchCount==4){
            rowsCount++
            matchCount = 0;
        }         
    } 
}

END{
    shareHolders = jsonValidateAndPrint(shareholdersArray, rowsCount - 1, shareholdersJsonSchema, 4, errorArray)

    shareHoldersErrors = jsonPrint(errorArray, length(errorArray) / length(errorsSchema), errorsSchema)

    resultArray[1,1] = "\n[\n" shareHolders "\n]\n"
    resultArray[1,2] = "\n[\n" shareHoldersErrors "\n]\n"

    resultJson = jsonPrint(resultArray, 1, resultSchema)
    print resultJson    
}
```

Produces output:

```
{"ShareHolders":
[
{"Imie":"JanA","Nazwisko":"NowakA","PESEL":null,"Funkcja":"PrezesA"},
{"Imie":"Ja\"nD","Nazwisko":"NowakD","PESEL":11111111111,"Funkcja":"PrezesD"},
{"Imie":"JanC","Nazwisko":"NowakC","PESEL":null,"Funkcja":"PrezesC"}
]
,"Errors":
[
{"PropertyName":"PESEL","Message":"Value 11111111111A not match format: ^[0-9]{11}$ ","PositionIndex":1},
{"PropertyName":"PESEL","Message":"Value 12342C not match format: ^[0-9]{11}$ ","PositionIndex":3}
]
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your string trim with `function trim(s) { gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/, "", s); return s }`

Comment: @djsowa, `awk` solution added here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479179/5866580 too could help you. Check it once and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at a gawk solution.  The indenting isn't perfect and the results aren't ordered (see "Sorting" note below), but it's at least able to walk a true multidimensional array recursively and should produce valid, parsable JSON from any array.  **Bonus:** the data array *is* the schema.  Array keys become JSON keys.  There's no need to create a separate schema array in addition to the data array.

Just be sure to use the [true multidimensional](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html#Arrays-of-Arrays) `array[d1][d2][d3]...` convention of constructing your data array, rather than the [concatenated index](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional) `array[d1,d2,d3...]` convention.

### Update:

I've got an updated JSON gawk script posted as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/calraith/5c85d17b28e96f49e067f9b054a6fdbb).  Although the script below is tested as working with OP's data, **I might've made improvements since this post was last edited.**  Please see the Gist for the most thoroughly tested, bug-squashed version.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }

$1 ~ "imie" { record[++idx]["name"] = $2 }
$1 ~ "nazwisko" { record[idx]["surname"] = $2 }
$1 ~ "pesel" { record[idx]["ID"] = $2 }
$1 ~ "funkcja" { record[idx]["role"] = $2 }

END { print serialize(record, "\t") }

# ==== FUNCTIONS ====

function join(arr, sep, _p, i) {
    # syntax: join(array, string separator)
    # returns a string

    for (i in arr) {
        _p["result"] = _p["result"] ~ "[[:print:]]" ? _p["result"] sep arr[i] : arr[i]
    }
    return _p["result"]
}

function quote(str) {
    gsub(/\\/, "\\\\", str)
    gsub(/\r/, "\\r", str)
    gsub(/\n/, "\\n", str)
    gsub(/\t/, "\\t", str)
    return "\"" str "\""
}

function serialize(arr, indent_with, depth, _p, i, idx) {
    # syntax: serialize(array of arrays, indent string)
    # returns a JSON formatted string

    # sort arrays on key, ensures [...] values remain properly ordered
    if (!PROCINFO["sorted_in"]) PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"

    # determine whether array is indexed or associative
    for (i in arr) {
        _p["assoc"] = or(_p["assoc"], !(++_p["idx"] in arr))
    }

    # if associative, indent
    if (_p["assoc"]) {
        for (i = ++depth; i--;) {
            _p["end"] = _p["indent"]; _p["indent"] = _p["indent"] indent_with
        }
    }

    for (i in arr) {
        # If key length is 0, assume its an empty object
        if (!length(i)) return "{}"

        # quote key if not already quoted
        _p["key"] = i !~ /^".*"$/ ? quote(i) : i

        if (isarray(arr[i])) {
            if (_p["assoc"]) {
                _p["json"][++idx] = _p["indent"] _p["key"] ": " \
                    serialize(arr[i], indent_with, depth)
            } else {
                # if indexed array, dont print keys
                _p["json"][++idx] = serialize(arr[i], indent_with, depth)
            }
        } else {
            # quote if not numeric, boolean, null, already quoted, or too big for match()
            if (!((arr[i] ~ /^[0-9]+([\.e][0-9]+)?$/ && arr[i] !~ /^0[0-9]/) ||
                arr[i] ~ /^true|false|null|".*"$/) || length(arr[i]) > 1000)
                arr[i] = quote(arr[i])

            _p["json"][++idx] = _p["assoc"] ? _p["indent"] _p["key"] ": " arr[i] : arr[i]
        }
    }

    # I trial and errored the hell out of this. Problem is, gawk cant distinguish between
    # a value of null and no value.  I think this hack is as close as I can get, although
    # [""] will become [].
    if (!_p["assoc"] && join(_p["json"]) == "\"\"") return "[]"

    # surround with curly braces if object, square brackets if array
    return _p["assoc"] ? "{\n" join(_p["json"], ",\n") "\n" _p["end"] "}" \
        : "[" join(_p["json"], ", ") "]"
}
```

Output resulting from OP's example data:

```
[{
        "ID": "1234A",
        "name": "JanA",
        "role": "PrezesA",
        "surname": "NowakA"
}, {
        "ID": "12341D",
        "name": "JanD",
        "role": "PrezesD",
        "surname": "NowakD"
}, {
        "ID": "12342C",
        "name": "JanC",
        "role": "PrezesC",
        "surname": "NowakC"
}, {
        "name": "Tomek"
}]
```

---

#### Sorting

Although the results by default are ordered in a manner only gawk understands, it is possible for gawk to sort the results on a field.  If you'd like to sort on the ID field for example, add this function:

```
function cmp_ID(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
    if (!isarray(v1) && v1 ~ /"ID"/ ) {
        return v1 < v2 ? -1 : (v1 != v2)
    }
}
```

Then insert this line within your `END` section above `print serialize(record)`:

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "cmp_ID"
```

See [Controlling Array Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @rojo There is a lot of basic gawk knowledge in Your example I will adapt to my own. I just pick my own implementation because I need a separation of data and schema.